# Akamai Website Fail-over trigger

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, failover

My organisation currently has 2 data centres from which it hosts its corporate website, with Akamai providing load-balancing, and other CDN services. Now, I'm told that if our server stack in 1 data centre stops responding, Akamai will automatically route the incoming traffic to the alternate data centre.

**Q:** Now my question is, what is the trigger that causes Akamai to initiate this routing?

*ie. Does Apache Http server literally have to stop listening/responding on port 80, or would returning non-2XX/3XX/4XX codes do it? (ie. have the application server return HTTP 500's)*

*If so, can it be configured to work on a context-by-context basis, so that if http://www.example.com/search goes down (app server returns HTTP 500), traffic to /search is routed elsewhere, but all other traffic still hits both stacks?*

**Q:** Also, how long after restoration of service would traffic start being routed back?

Comment: You should ask Akamai about all this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1)       This is one the fail-over, typically called Fail-over to Alternate Data Center "Mirror Fail-over"·

Fail-over can be directed to use the backup site in case the primary is unavailable. You may choose to have the backup site be different from the origin site - for example, it may contain reduced functionality or content. Upon receiving a request for content that resides on the primary site and determining that the primary site is unavailable, the Akami edge server will obtain the request content[ or its defined substitute] from the mirror site "Alternative DC" in a manner invisible to the end user.·

(2) The restoration depends on your thresholds. What is your frequency of your check and how long your response need to be validated. When I was using Akamai. I add some extra checks to ensure the DC restoration...like

- Edge bandwidth usage drops or bursts
- Does Origin server within a data center fails.·
- Is there a Origin connection failure  "Associating to DC load balancer"·
- Origin DNS failure·

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me see what options I have access to now that I can contact Akamai.